# PyGame App NameError: name 'event' is not defined

Tags: python, pygame

This is extremely annoying and I don't know why it's happening. Here's the code:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

def createWin(x, y):
    winCreate = True
    while winCreate:
        win = pygame.display.set_mode((x, y))
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

createWin(1000, 1000)
```

I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'event' is not defined
```

Comment: The error is exactly what it says. The variable `event` is nowhere defined. I think you should look at the tutorial again and find where the event variable is defined. I am sure pygame has some good tutorials

Comment: `event` isn't defined. It's not a primitive in python. I'm assuming that you are looking at a tutorial somewhere where `event` is being used. Check that tutorial for where they define `event`, i.e. `event = ...`, or `from X import event`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do -

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
```

Otherwise python will not recognize `event`!

Comment: is possible to wrap this loop inside a function and return the variable event?