# name event is not defined

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote this lines of code:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        PlayerX_change = -0.3
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        PlayerX_change = 0.3
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        PlayerX_change = 0.3
```

I get this error:

```
name 'event' is not defined.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you don't have any variable named `event`.

Comment: [Do a google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58632848/pygame-app-nameerror-name-event-is-not-defined). This is the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should call event from your pygame library before using it , so make sure that you imported pygame , if not add this in your first line of code
`import pygame` 
And add this before using your conditions:
`for event in pygame.event.get():`

Comment: I did it but it still didn't work

Comment: https://ibb.co/vLSLqY1 look

Comment: First of all , you need to declare `PlayerX_change =0`  before all the if statements . and better to use `elif` after the first condition on event.type ( it means that if the first condition on event.type is not true they try the secodn statement and ...) and the last statement on event.type change `if` with `else`